# How to avoid duplicating a function body

Tags: kotlin

I want to write a helper function to simplify viewmodel calls to services. In the library that this project uses (and which I cannot modify) there are a few different promise types that need to be used in the same exact way in every function, the only thing that varies is the (()->Unit) lambdas passed to them.

Despite these promise types having the exact same members and being used the same way, they don't share a common interface so in order to write this helper function, it would seem to me that I would have to overload it and duplicate the function body. Is there any way to avoid doing that?

A sort-of minimal example:

```
private fun myHelper(promise: PromiseTypeA | PromiseTypeB | PromiseTypeC, cbSuccess: ()->Unit, cbFail: ()->Unit) {
    loaderBlock();
    compMan.add(promise.sub(ioScheduler).obs(uiScheduler).onSuccess(cbSuccess).onFail(cbFail))
}
```

In reality, I would also nest the passed lambdas and do stuff with them making this function body much longer but this should illustrate the situation. PromiseTypeA, PromiseTypeB and PromiseTypeC all have the same members, get used the same way but have no common interface or ancestor. The OR operator I used in argument definition represents what I'd like to be able to do (like in TypeScript) but I cannot. How do I do the equivalent in kotlin?

Comment: Does `promise.sub()` return the same type of object for all types of Promise?

Comment: @Tenfour04 no, all the promise methods listed here return the promise itself with its own respective type

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin is strict on types and doesn't do "duck typing". If the different promise types don't explicitly implement a common interface, but just *happen to have* the same member names, these are conceptually different members.

The code is therefore not "duplicated" (at least in the eyes of Kotlin) because the function calls are technically not the same.

There is no way that I know of to make Kotlin understand that you want to give the same semantics to these names (without changing the source code of these types to make them implement an interface). I think this is the sort of things that the "traits" feature would enable if it were added to the language.

Comment: Answer is conceptually correct, but I feel some part of kotlin uses this non-common interface logic somehow, such as a Delegate doesn't need to implement a common interface, just need two operator functions i.e. getValue and setValue with appropriate parameters. And that for loop, which just need a iterator() method in the given object to iterate through.

Comment: Operators are sort-of hardcoded things that the compiler can understand so that it can enable very specific language features (the set of supported operator functions is fixed, and each of them is associated with some language syntax). I'm afraid there is no more general mechanism that user code can actually use to have this sort of effect (but maybe I just missed something in the language).

Answer (score 0):

There is no "Union types" in Kotlin, so to unify usage of this classes, you will need to:

1. Define a common interface

```kotlin
interface Promise {
    fun sub(): Promise
    fun obs(): Promise
    fun onSuccess(): Promise
    fun onFail(): Promise
}
```

2. Write some boilerplate code:

```kotlin
fun PromiseTypeA.toPromise()  = object : Promise {
    override fun sub(): Promise {
        this@toPromise.sub()
        return this
    }

    override fun obs(): Promise {
        this@toPromise.obs()
        return this
    }

    override fun onSuccess(): Promise {
        this@toPromise.onSuccess()
        return this
    }

    override fun onFail(): Promise {
        this@toPromise.onFail()
        return this
    }
}

//and so on for other types of promises
```

After that everything is easy: define your helper function for `Promise` parameter type

```kotlin
private fun myHelper(promise: Promise, cbSuccess: ()->Unit, cbFail: ()->Unit) {
//...
}
```

and call it with:

```kotlin
myHelper(promiseA.toPromise(), {/*...*/},  {/*...*/})
```